# Challenge: Choosing all the top items first in sorted arrays (not merely combining all possible values)

Tags: javascript, arrays, postgresql, sorting, combinations

**Note: This question is not about simply combining all possible values**

Hello,

This is not an enquiry on how to combine all possible values. That is easy enough. I am looking for a special way of doing it.

First a bit of background:

I want to combine sorted items so that the highest ranked items are combined first. Here is an example.

Lets suppose we have an array of arrays such that each element is of arbitrary length as such (example code given in Javascript)

```
const arrays = [
  [0,1,2,3,...],
  [0,1,2,3,...],
  [0,1,2,3,...],
  ...
]
```

I'm looking for a function that would provide out as such

```
[
 [0,0,0,0,0...]
 [1,0,0,0,0...]
 [1,1,0,0,0...]
 [1,0,1,0,0...]
 [1,0,0,1,0...]
 ...
 [1,1,1,0,0...]
 [1,1,0,1,0...]
 [1,1,0,0,1...]
 ...
 [2,0,0,0,0...]
 [0,2,0,0,0...]
 [0,0,2,0,0...]
 ...
 [1,2,0,0,0...]
 [1,0,2,0,0...]
 [1,0,0,2,0...]
 ...
]
```

To give a more concrete example,

```
const carRank = ['Ferrari','BMW','Honda']
const drinkRank = ['wine','tea','water']
const skiRank = ['Chamonix','Tahoe','Big Bear']

combineSortedArraysWithBestFirst( carRank, drinkRank, skiRank )
```

The result would be

```
[
 ['Ferrari','wine','Chamonix'],
 ['BMW','wine','Chamonix'],
 ['Ferrari','tea','Chamonix'],
 ['Ferrari','wine','Tahoe'],
 ['BMW','tea','Chamonix'],
 ['BMW','wine','Tahoe'],
 ['BMW','tea','Tahoe'],
 ['Hona','wine','Chamonix'],
 ['Ferrari','water','Chamonix'],
 ['Ferrari','wine','Big Bear'],
 ...
]
```

In other words, high-ranked or items closes to the top of the stack are preferred.

Please be aware that I don't want a mere combination of all possible values. For brevity, with SQL / Postgresql that would be achieved thusly:

```
select * from unnest(array1), unnest(array2);
```

Again, not what I want as that would produce something like this

```
[0,0]
[1,0]
[2,0]
[3,0]
[4,0]
```

where I am looking for something like this

```
[0,0]
[1,0]
[0,1]
[1,1]
[2,0]
[0,2]
```

UPDATE:

For what its worth, here is the solution in SQL (PostgreSQL) using array indexes as values

```
select 
  * 
from 
  unnest(ARRAY[0,1,2,3]) first, 
  unnest(ARRAY[0,1,2,3]) second, 
  unnest(ARRAY[0,1,2,3]) third, 
  lateral(
    select first^2+second^2+third^2 as values_squared_sum
  ) as sum 
order by 
  values_squared_sum;
```

Update 2, sample SQL/PostgreSQL solution

```
select 
  * 
from 
  unnest_with_index(ARRAY['Ferarri','BMW','Honda']) cars,
  unnest_with_index(ARRAY['wine','tea','water']) drinks,
  unnest_with_index(ARRAY['Chamonix','Tahoe','Big Bear']) resorts
order by
  (cars.index^2 + drinks.index^2 + resorts.index ^2);
```

`unnest_with_index` is a simple function that adds a row number to the unnested array.

Comment: you need to give the data rank values. 'Ferrari', 'BMW', and 'wine' might have high-value to you, but to the computer it's just a string.

Comment: They are already ranked in order -- sorted, so the first already has a higher value. I will update with a sample solution in SQL for you, see above.